# FFmpeg: yuv422p10 encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding

I am using ffmpeg (and still a novice with it) to extract each frame from a video that is coming from a DeckLink SDI 4K.
And I am calling ffmpeg from a software I am building via a pipeline, here is the command:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -format_code Hp50 -raw_format yuv422p10 -video_input sdi -f decklink -vsync 0 -draw_bars true -i 'DeckLink SDI 4K' -f segment -segment_time 0.020000 -f rawvideo -
```

It generates each frame but I am unable to extract the yuv data.
I read from the Internet that it is encoded as 10 bits planar uncompressed yuv frame (fourcc: p210?).
Unfortunately I am unable to generate any valid data since I do not know where exactly are the 'y', the 'u' and the 'v'.
Just to mention I am decoding each frame myself.

I need this input to make some computation on each frame in the yuv 10bits colorspace.

Any help on the yuv422p10 decoding is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -format_code Hp50 -raw_format yuv422p10 -video_input sdi -f decklink -draw_bars true -i 'DeckLink SDI 4K' -pix_fmt yuv422p10be -f rawvideo -`

yuv422p10 denotes that the three components are arranged as planes, which are sent one after the other.

For each frame, the first array of size `2 x W x H` bytes is your Y plane. Then the next `2 x (W / 2 + W % 2) x H` bytes, that's the U plane. Finally, the next `2 x (W / 2 + W % 2) x H` bytes is the V plane. Then follows the next frame.

The multiplier of 2 above denotes the padded sample size in bytes. In each 2 byte sample of a pixel component, the lower 10-bits encode the data.

Comment: I am still getting values lower than the black for Y values.
The black should be set to 64 for 10 bits yuv.
With values lower than 64 allowed at computing time.

Comment: But can you decode now?

Comment: I can decode the U and V planes.
I am stil unable to decode the Y plane. The frame seems to be shifted at random and it does not match the U and V planes

Comment: Supposing 'i' from 0 to (W / 2 + W % 2) x H, how do you build each macropixel?
What I suppose is: Y[2 * i] Y[2 * i +1] U[i] V[i]. It seems to work for U and V but not for Y.

Comment: There's no remainder component (`W%2`) for the Y plane. Suppose your frame is 5x3 then the first `2x5x3 = 30` bytes is for the Y plane, Top-to-bottom, left-to-right. Then the next `2x(int(W/2)+W%2)xH = 2x(2+1)x3 = 18` bytes for the U plane, followed by 18 bytes for V, followed by 30 bytes for Y of next frame and so on.